# MATLAB parfor and classification/use of variables

Tags: matlab, classification, temporary, parfor

I do not have much experience with parallelization in MATLAB (<2 weeks of do-it-yourself), still I got a parfor loop working, similar to this:

```
N = 11;
var1 = zeros(N, 2);

parfor n=1:N
  a = zeros(3, 3);
  b = zeros(3, 3);

  [a, b] = myfun(<arguments>);

  var1(n, :) = [sum(sum(a,1),2) sum(sum(b,1),2);]

end

<portion of non parallelized code that makes use of var1 contents>
```

If I understood the documentation/examples so far, 'var1' is classified as a sliced variable and 'a' and 'b' as temporary variables. I'm using 'var1' this way because I need to use its content after the execution of the parfor loop.

I also wanted to use 'a' and 'b' variables as sliced variables to avoid reinitialization/unnecessary memory reallocation(?)/increase parallel performance.

I tried something like this for variable 'a':

```
N = 11;
var1 = zeros(N, 2);
**a = zeros(3, 3, N);**

parfor n=1:N
  b = zeros(3, 3);

  [**a(:,:,n)**, b] = myfun(<arguments>);

  var1(n, :) = [sum(sum(**a(:,:,n)** ,1),2) sum(sum(b,1),2);]

end

<another portion of non parallelized code that makes use of var1 contents>
```

with the intent of making workers use pieces of the same region in memory, but I get the error "The variable a in a parfor cannot be classified."

So... why can't it be classified and used as a sliced variable, like var1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not a good idea. A sliced variable means communication because the primary instance sends it to the worker and receives it from there. It also means double memory usage because the primary instance keeps the variable and (in slices) the workers.

Your first version is fine. You could delete the lines `a = zeros(3, 3);b = zeros(3, 3);` .

This is how it would look like with a sliced variable `a`

```
N = 11;
var1 = zeros(N, 2);
a = zeros(3, 3,N);
parfor n=1:N

  [a(:,:,n), b] = myfun(2);

  var1(n, :) = [sum(sum(a(:,:,n),1),2) sum(sum(b,1),2);]
end
```

This is the code I would recommend:

```
N = 11;
var1 = zeros(N, 2);
parfor n=1:N

  [a, b] = myfun(2);

  var1(n, :) = [sum(a(:)) sum(b(:))]
end
```